# system freezes after installing ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I've tried 3 times now to install ubuntu 11.10 from a cd onto an 8 year old Dell inspiron but after installation the system just freezes. System has 2.66GHz CPU, 1GB RAM and 120GB HD. There is no way to perform any operation, I can only force shut down. Has anyone encountered similar difficulties and found a solution?

The video card is NVIDIA geforcefx5200.  The screen is almost blank after booting - the top userbar is present but not functioning and nothing else appears on the screen.

I've managed to install ubuntu 10.04 without any problems now instead

Comment: What do you mean by "freeze"? Does it boot into a blank screen? If so this is a know problem with some video cards.

Comment: might be from graphic card driver try to uninstall it or reinstall ubuntu and update all thing expect you video card driver

Comment: maybe you should do a memtest and a disk test with your liveCD first.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, because some missing files at the installation CD. Purple blank screen. May be helpful: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>del</kbd>, then <kbd>enter</kbd>, after you can get `modprob`, type `help`, get list of command, type `lsfmd` (soft mod), type `exit`. If you get purple screen with options try 'recovery mod'. But, this is temporary solution.